# Is it acceptable to paint kitchen walls in alkyd?

Tags: painting, alkyd

The kitchen has very little revealed wall space, and we were wondering if it is ok to use alkyd paint on the walls (to keep it simple). It would be the same white paint as used on the cabinets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, if you don't mind the texture being the same as the cabinets, there is no technical reason you can't use it, unless the walls currently have latex based paint.  Alkyd is an oil based product and may lift a latex based product if used as a top coat.

Comment: The walls are currently PVA-primed sheet rock. What do you mean by texture in this context?

Comment: by texture, I meant gloss level. Cabinets are usually done in a full or semi gloss and walls tend to be eggshell or satin finish.  That stuff is personal preference however.  PVA is a latex base product, high in vinyl acrylics, dries very fast so not to soak the paper on drywall. An excellent choice of primer for new rock.  Test and area with the oil based product and let it cure for 24 hours. You may get away with it, but watch carefully for small wrinkles to develop.

Comment: I think we will play it safe and use a water-based product on the walls due to your cautionary note regarding wrinkles. Thanks!